# How to visualize panda robot in gazebo while moving it with my own cpp script

Tags: rviz, control, visualization

So I'm using franka_ros where I added my own package that includes some scripts that executes a trajectory for the robot using `robot.control` class from libfranka. I tested this script in the real robot works.

Now I want to visualize this movement in gazebo while robot is working. I have tried to visualize using franka_visualize package and then executing my code but whenever my code runs it shows an error and the visualization stops, as the `robot_joint_state_publisher` crashes. This is the error (there is no log file, dont know why):

```
[traj_execute_node-2] process has died [pid 48980, exit code -6, cmd /home/mikel/Escritorio/frankaWs/devel/lib/panda_code/trajExecute __name:=traj_execute_node __log:=/home/mikel/.ros/log/eeabd1ea-61ed-11ee-a206-8d39358d7414/traj_execute_node-2.log].
log file: /home/mikel/.ros/log/eeabd1ea-61ed-11ee-a206-8d39358d7414/traj_execute_node-2*.log
```

This is my launch file:

```
    <!-- my_launch_file.launch -->

<launch>
  <arg name="load_gripper" default="true" />   <arg name="robot_ip"  default="172.16.0.2" />   <arg name="publish_rate" default="30" />   <arg name="robot" default="panda" doc="choose your robot. Possible values: [panda, fr3]"/>    <!-- Run your main.cpp executable as a ROS node -->   <node name="traj_execute_node" pkg="panda_code" type="trajExecute" output="screen"/>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find franka_description)/robots/$(arg robot)/$(arg robot).urdf.xacro arm_id:=panda hand:=$(arg load_gripper)" />

  <node name="robot_joint_state_publisher" pkg="franka_visualization" type="robot_joint_state_publisher" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find franka_visualization)/config/robot_settings.yaml" />
    <param name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)" />
    <param name="publish_rate" value="$(arg publish_rate)" />   </node>

  <node name="gripper_joint_state_publisher" pkg="franka_visualization" type="gripper_joint_state_publisher" output="screen" if="$(arg load_gripper)">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find franka_visualization)/config/gripper_settings.yaml" />
    <param name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)" />
    <param name="publish_rate" value="$(arg publish_rate)" />   </node>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" output="screen">
    <param name="rate" value="$(arg publish_rate)" />
    <rosparam param="source_list">[robot_joint_state_publisher/joint_states, gripper_joint_state_publisher/joint_states]</rosparam>   </node>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />   <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find franka_visualization)/launch/franka_visualization.rviz -f $(arg robot)_link0 --splash-screen $(find franka_visualization)/splash.png"/> </launch>
```

And this is my main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <franka/exception.h>
#include <franka/robot.h>
#include <franka/model.h>
#include <chrono>

//includes propios
#include "TrajHelper.h"
#include "MathHelper.h"
#include "Q7TrajGenerator.h"

std::string aString;

int main(){
        const std::string robot_ip = "172.16.0.2";


    try {
        //crear objeto de la clase robot, que permite crear una conexion con la controladora con la ip seleccionada
        franka::Robot robot(robot_ip,franka::RealtimeConfig::kIgnore);

        //define los limites de torques y fuerzas en el robot
        robot.setCollisionBehavior(
                    {{20.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0, 16.0, 14.0, 12.0}}, {{20.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0, 16.0, 14.0, 12.0}},
                    {{20.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0, 16.0, 14.0, 12.0}}, {{20.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0, 16.0, 14.0, 12.0}},
                    {{20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0}}, {{20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0}},
                    {{20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0}}, {{20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0}});
        //crea un objeto del tipo Robot state y recibo datos de los sensores
        franka::RobotState state;
        state = robot.readOnce();

        //inicializar las variables de acuerdo al estado inicial del robot
        std::array<double,7> robotInitPos = state.q;
        std::array<double,7> robotInitVel = state.dq;

        QVector7 qs = MathHelper::array2qv7(robotInitPos);
        QVector7 dqs = MathHelper::array2qv7(robotInitVel);
        QVector7 ddqs =  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

//      QVector7 qsFin =  { 0, 0, 0, -1.59, 0, 1.57, -0};
        QVector7 qsFin =  { -0.78, 0, 0, -1.59, 0, 1.57, -0};
        QVector7 dqsFin = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        QVector7 ddqsFin = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        double t0 = 0;
        double tf = 5;
        double sampling_time = 1.0e-3;
        double TrackSamples =tf/sampling_time;

        std::vector<QVector7> torqueToFile;
        std::vector<QVector7> posToFile;
        std::vector<QVector7> velToFile;

        //calcular las trajectorias deseadas
        std::tuple<std::vector<std::array<double, 7>>, std::vector<std::array<double, 7>>, std::vector<std::array<double, 7>>> Trj = Q7TrajGenerator::getQuinticTrajArray(qs, qsFin, dqs, dqsFin,ddqs,ddqsFin,
                                                                       t0, tf, sampling_time);
        std::vector<std::array<double, 7>> qd = std::get<0>(Trj);

        //cronometro
        std::chrono::steady_clock sc;
        auto start = sc.now();

        //print pos inicial
        std::cout << "Joint init positions: "<< std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)
        {
            std::cout << qs[i] << " "<< std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << "press intro to continue..." << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin,aString);

        // Creates the control loop and executes the path in joints until finishes and returns MotionFinished
        robot.control([&qd, &TrackSamples,&torqueToFile, &posToFile, &velToFile](const franka::RobotState& robot_state/* state */, franka::Duration /* period */) -> franka::JointPositions
                    {
                static unsigned int iter = 0;
                //mientras iter sea mas pequeño que toda la longitud de la trayectoria,
                //crea un objeto del tipo JointPositions y actualiza la trayectoria deseada del robot
                if (iter < TrackSamples) {
                    franka::JointPositions posCommand = {
                        {qd[iter][0], qd[iter][1], qd[iter][2], qd[iter][3], qd[iter][4], qd[iter][5], qd[iter][6]}
                    };

                    posToFile.push_back(MathHelper::array2qv7(robot_state.q));
                    velToFile.push_back(MathHelper::array2qv7(robot_state.dq));
//                  torqueToFile.push_back(MathHelper::array2qv7(robot_state.tau_J));

                    ++iter;
                    return posCommand;
                } else
                {

                    TrajHelper::confDataToFile("DataToFile.txt", torqueToFile, posToFile, velToFile, false);
                    //cuando termina la trayectoria, guardar la ultima posicion y llamar MotionFinished para terminar el lazo
                    franka::JointPositions lastPosCommand = {
                                {qd[TrackSamples-1][0], qd[TrackSamples-1][1], qd[TrackSamples-1][2],
                                 qd[TrackSamples-1][3], qd[TrackSamples-1][4], qd[TrackSamples-1][5],
                                 qd[TrackSamples-1][6]}
                            };
                    std::cout << "Robot Final Position: \n";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
                        std::cout << lastPosCommand.q[i] << " " << std::endl;;
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    return franka::MotionFinished(lastPosCommand);
                }
            });
        auto end = sc.now();
        auto cycleTime = static_cast<std::chrono::duration < double >> (end - start);
        std::cout << std::endl << "each cycle time was: " << cycleTime.count() / TrackSamples << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl << "total cycle time was: " << cycleTime.count() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (const franka::ControlException& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Control exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }

    return 0;
}
```

My logic says that robot.control interferes somehow with the robot_joint_state_publisher node. Please any advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you trying to visualize the current state of the real robot arm, or are you trying to run a gazebo simulation of the arm?

Comment: For now I just want to visualize my current state on the real robot

Comment: OK, you don't use gazebo for a visualization like that, you use rviz. Specifically you want the RobotModel plugin to rviz.

Comment: For debugging your crash, you can start to narrow it down by looking at the joint values published by your node named `robot_joint_state_publisher`. If any joint value becomes NaN or Infinity, that's a problem. Another thing you can do is attach the gdb debugger to the `traj_execute_node` linux process and get a backtrace (bt) after the crash happens. If you add the backtrace to this question, it may provide a hint as to what is unhappy.